# Jfreechart without X11

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'm using Jfreechart for creating charts. I'm creating `BufferedImage` of chart and writing it in `OutputStream`.

It's working fine with display environment, but its Not working In `headless` environment.

Please help how do you make it work in such an environment.

Exception I got in log:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/WebAdmin] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.] with root cause
java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$200(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:65)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:110)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:74)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:102)
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:81)
    at sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.isLocalDisplay(SwingUtilities2.java:1457)
    at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel.initComponentDefaults(MetalLookAndFeel.java:1556)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicLookAndFeel.getDefaults(BasicLookAndFeel.java:148)
    at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel.getDefaults(MetalLookAndFeel.java:1592)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:536)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:576)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.initializeDefaultLAF(UIManager.java:1345)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.initialize(UIManager.java:1455)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.maybeInitialize(UIManager.java:1422)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.getDefaults(UIManager.java:656)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.getColor(UIManager.java:698)
    at org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart.<clinit>(JFreeChart.java:263)
    at org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory.createBarChart(ChartFactory.java:893)
```

And the part of catalina.sh I have edited:

```
#   JSSE_HOME       (Optional) May point at your Java Secure Sockets Extension
#                   (JSSE) installation, whose JAR files will be added to the
#                   system class path used to start Tomcat.
#
#   CATALINA_PID    (Optional) Path of the file which should contains the pid
#                   of catalina startup java process, when start (fork) is used
#
# $Id: catalina.sh 609438 2008-01-06 22:14:28Z markt $
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -server -Xms1536m 
-Xmx1536m -XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m 
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC"
```

Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You most likely want to invoke your Java program in [headless mode](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/headless/):

```
java -Djava.awt.headless=true -cp ... come.your.Class
```

Alternatively, at runtime before any graphics code (e.g. in a `static {}` block):

```
System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");
```

Comment: Thank you Philipp Reichart. I have set my JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
 in Catalina.sh . but still its not working.

Comment: If you get an exception in the Tomcat logs, please add the stacktrace and any other information about how it is not working to your question (the comments are too small). The relevant part of where you edited `Catalina.sh` might also help.

Comment: Thanks Philipp Reichart its working after setting 
java.awt.headless=true

Earlier another class of mine which extends Applet was giving problem after setting this property to true. But now I have removed applet dependency and its working for JFreeChart.